# Configure the domain name for local server using Node.js

Tags: node.js

I have the following server configuration code using Express.js :

```
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

const express = require('express');
const bodyparser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();

const path = require('path');
const api = require('./apiUrl')({});


app.use(bodyparser.json());
app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.use(express.static(__dirname))
app.use('/api', api);

app.listen(port, ()=>{
    console.log(`Server Listening to the port ${port}`);
});
```

So, I wanna assign a domain name,

For example: I wanna use www.example.com:5000 instead of localhost:5000. How should I configure domain name for my local server ? Any links I could refer to is much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At first, the `localhost` point to loopback IP `127.0.0.1`. This is defined on hosts file located at `/etc/hosts`, for Linux systems, and at `c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts`, for Windows.

On hosts file, you can see, the entry:

> 127.0.0.1       localhost

The hosts file is used preferentially to other name resolution methods, even before looking in DNS.

Thereby, if you intend run your app locally available at `www.example.com`, just add the bellow entry on hosts file:

> 127.0.0.1 www.example.com

On other hand, if you intend run you app over internet avaiable at `www.example.com` you should register this host with some DNS service.

Answer (score -1):

Updated:

search about 'host file' or 'hosts file'

and I added a comment with some useful links

good luck

Comment: Dear jay instead of posting a link here (which could become invalid in the future) post relevant portions from that link

Comment: @Alcatraz
here is some useful link
[how-to-edit-your-hosts-file](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/27350/beginner-geek-how-to-edit-your-hosts-file/)

Comment: @Alcatraz [hosts-file(wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file))